# egrep not giving result in while loop, however working individually

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I'm trying to grep a regex pattern("^[\w+[0-9]{5,6}]$" ) after echo one line ( example [abc_testing_12345]) .
Its working fine when I execute it on command line by defining two variable, input and pattern.
But when I use the same in a while loop and getting value of input from a file, it doesn't work.

I have seen multiple threads on internet and tried to use the options but it didn't work.

Sample working Code :

```
    pattern="^\[\w+[0-9]{5,6}\]$"
    input="[abc_testing_12345]"
    echo "$input" | egrep -c "$pattern
```

this prints value 1

but when I populate 'input' variable from a file and then try to grep, it doesn't print value 1

Sample Code :

```
pattern="^\[\w+[0-9]{5,6}\]$"
cat inputFile | grep "\[" | while read line
do
echo "$line" | egrep -c "$pattern"
done
```

the result of this code is 0

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. The script you've provided returns `1` as long as `inputfile` contains a line matching `$pattern`, like:

```
[abc_testing_12345]
```

However I'd suggest rewriting the `while` loop as:

```
while read line                                                          
do                                                                          
    echo "$line" | grep -c "$pattern"                                      
done <<< $(grep "\[" inputfile)
```

Or even avoid the `while` loop with:

```
grep -c "$pattern" inputfile
```